# How to optimize Unity scene with 125,000+ GameObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization

I am currently working on a program that requires me to spawn in excess of 125,000 sphere-objects into my scene at predetermined points (x, y, z) and I have run into the obvious problem of lag.

Before I give specifics, I wanted to point out that I have already searched for answers on this topic but I was not able to find an answer given the fact that people (understandably) run to the immediate fallback of suggesting that the OP doesn't spawn so many objects, however, this is not an option in this case as I need to do this for my application to work as intended.

As for specifics, the objects I am spawning are Unity Sphere 3D Object prefabs at a scale of 0.50 on x, y, and z with a material property attached to it that affects its color.

If anyone has any ideas on how to improve performance, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are there colliders on these objects as well?

Comment: How/why are you spawning these objects? —Do you need them all to spawn at once? Will they all be on-screen simultaneously? How long do you need them to exist for? What method are you currently using for this?

Comment: You need to optimize the game or the scene?

Comment: @Ruzihm There are no colliders on them.

Comment: @Pikanchion They need to all be spawned at once and viewed (they will be on screen simultaneously. They will stay in the world until the user exits.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I'd look into that may work depending on what you're doing for your scene. First thing I'd suggest would be occlusion culling (if it applies) - basically, only rendering the GameObjects that are visible at the current point in time. You'll still have a reference to the GameObject in your scene, however those references will only actually be rendered if they are visible to the camera. There's numerous ways to do this, Unity has a baked-in method if you prefer but I've seen other methods around.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

If they all have to be in view, then there could be some ways to make it easier, granted all of this is off the top of my head while I'm at work, but maybe you could fudge the material that needs to be rendered a bit? Meaning, does *every* sphere need to have the material rendered on it or could you get away with 1/2 or 1/3 of the spheres having the material? I'm not sure what you are doing in your scene, but do the actual Mesh and Texture renderers need to be displayed, or could you get away with just spawning a portion of your spheres as colliders alone?

Just some food for thought, let me know what you think! I'm happy to help brainstorm.

Comment: Comments aren't appropriate for a discussion. Consider discussing this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201732/https-stackoverflow-com-a-58664438-1092820)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these tips solve problem:

- First change the shader you have if you currently use PBR for one of MatCap.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/095jo.jpg)
- Use lights in bake mode and light probes.
  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightMode-Baked.html
  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightProbes.html
- If the object has logic change it to the flyweight design pattern, another pattern that can help you is pool object and factory.